# How to get Twitter profile image in iphone?

Tags: iphone, twitter

I am creating an app in which i want to show the current profile image of twitter of user after he successfully logs into his account. till now i am able to log in to twitter successfully but don't know how to get the image of profile.

I think i have to call users/show method from the api, if anyone has idea how to do it please help.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show

gives the basic information about a user, parse it to get url of the profilepic

Comment: as given in example , send a request http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=TwitterAPI&include_entities=true, it returns a json which has profile_image_url